# How can I copy shapes from one slide to another slide in c#?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, shapes

I need to insert shape(s) from presentation1 to presentation2. We can insert a slide like

pptApp.Presentations[Presentation2].Slides.InsertFromFile("presenation1", 10,2,2);

But I want only the shapes from Presentation1.slide(x)  inserted to Presentation2.slide(y).

How can i Do this in C#?  Please help me.

Thanks
P2000

Comment: do you know how to get a shape? if so, just do a `.Duplicate` on it and paste in Presentation2.

Comment: Please tell me the way of getting shapes from presentation1 and duplicating it in ppt2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var origSlide = origPres.Slides[slideNum];
var destSlide = newPres.Slides[slideNum];
foreach (Shape origShape in origSlide.Shapes)
{
    origShape.Copy();
    newPres.Slides.Paste(slideNum);
}
```